# Running a command as the first command in subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, command, subprocess

I have a function that will open a terminal:

```
def open_next_terminal():
    import subprocess

    def rand(path="/tmp"):
        acc = string.ascii_letters
        retval = []
        for _ in range(7):
            retval.append(random.choice(acc))
        return "{}/{}.sh".format(path, ''.join(retval))

    file_path = rand()
    with open(file_path, "a+") as data:
        data.write(
'''
#!/bin/bash
"$@"
exec $SHELL
'''
        )
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "bash", "{}".format(file_path)])
    return file_path
```

I want to run a command in this newly opened terminal before anything is done in it. For example:

```
subprocess.call(["sudo", "bash", "{}".format(file_path)]) #<= is called
ls #<= is run
 #<= some output of files and folders
root@host:~#  #<= the shell is now available
```

Does subprocess allow a way for me to run a "first command" during the initialization of the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the `shell=True` parameter to `subprocess.call`, and you can run multiple commands (delimited by semicolons or newlines) as a single string.

```
subprocess.call('your_first_command.sh; your_real_work.sh', shell=True)
```

Comment: Command injection is possible only if your command string is derived from user inputs. And even it is derived from user inputs, you can use [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to escape the portions that are from user inputs.

Comment: So other then this, there is no way to run a "first command"?

Comment: Not that I can think of, unfortunately.